# Xamarin.Forms - display multiple pages at once

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am converting a project from Xamarin Native (Android) to Xamarin.Forms with Shell. I already have working and published version for mobile phone, now I need to finish support for tablets.

In Xamarin Native for tablet I displayed multiple pages at once (on the left item selection and on the right detail information of selected item). Which was working quite well.

Unfortunately I do not know how to achieve this task in Xamarin.Forms. I found that FlyoutPage or MasterDetailPage serves for this purposes, but I am not sure whether any of it could be used as I am using Shell with FlyoutItems.

[image]
[image]

Maybe there is some different solution.
Basically I would need to put one ContentPage to green section (items on the screen) and second ContentPage to blue part of the picture.

Comment: There will single page only as per you requirement you need to create page partition and make it visible and hidden based on menu item selected

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the pages to ContentView, and then show it in a ContentView control

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32296218)

Answer (score -1):

> Unfortunately I do not know how to achieve this task in Xamarin.Forms.
> I found that FlyoutPage or MasterDetailPage serves for this purposes,
> but I am not sure whether any of it could be used as I am using Shell
> with FlyoutItems.

From document [MasterDetailPage Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.masterdetailpage?view=xamarin-forms),we know that:

> MasterDetailPage is obsolete as of version 5.0.0. Please use
> FlyoutPage instead.

So, you can use  [FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage) instead of `MasterDetailPage`.

And from document [Xamarin.Forms Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/introduction),we know that Xamarin.Forms Shell reduces the complexity of mobile application development by providing the fundamental features that most mobile applications require, including:

- A single place to describe the visual hierarchy of an application.
- A common navigation user experience.
- A URI-based navigation scheme that permits navigation to any page in
  the application.
- An integrated search handler.

In addition, Shell applications benefit from an increased rendering speed, and reduced memory consumption.

So,`Shell` is recommended if it meets your needs.

And the Shell has multiple features，for more details, you can check： https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/introduction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately even by the provided link I am still not sure how to achieve the functionality. I would still need flyout menu available, but to show item page (P1) and detail page (P2) all at once - I have edited the picture.

Comment: Just as Himanshu said,when we click on the menu on the left, only one page is displayed at a time if we use FlyoutPage or Shell.

Comment: So it means there is not way how to achieve it? Do I understand correctly the only way is to create brand new page which will contain XAML elements from P1 and P2?

Comment: `to create brand new page which will contain XAML elements from P1 and P2` is also a good idea, you can try it.