# xamarin forms: mvvm navigation on master detail structure

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

Using xamarin forms, I am trying to create an app for android tablet with layout navigation structure which should have
left side menu items and right side its pages in the same screen (no overlapping menu panel required in ux)
Master detail page is a option but it will create fly layout appearance and ux will not match upto the requirement.
I need mvvm structure on viewmodel navigation to its pages.
Any help would be appreciated on this.

Example:

[sample screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9al6A.png)

Comment: By the way, are you using  Shell in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: @HongxinSui I am not using shell in forms. shell will replace entire page when navigating to other viewmodels. I need 1 page and navigation menu left side and right side its content pages.

Comment: You may refer to this website: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815331/xamarin-forms-display-multiple-pages-at-once"

Comment: shell is creating overlapping menu panel.
I need 1 screen which should have 2 portion. left portion will have menu items and right portion will have content pages.